# Can't pass data down to angular child component in ngFor loop?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass the data "testData" down to the child component 'multi-card' but when I attempt to do so it returns this error.

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'app-multi-card'

I'm new to angular so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious.

Parent TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-information-general-multi',
  templateUrl: './information-general-multi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./information-general-multi.component.scss']
})
export class InformationGeneralMultiComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  testData = [
    {
      "name": "bingo"
    },
    {
      "name": "notta"
    }
  ]

}
```

Parent Template

```
    <div class='mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing'>

  <div class='mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet' *ngFor="let test of testData">
        <app-multi-card [data]="testData"></app-multi-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I haven't tried to call it in my child component am I supposed to import the data in child component or does that happen automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the decorator `@Input()` on a property called `data` in your child component. This property will be fed automatically by the binding.

Have a look in the documentation for this : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Thank you! I knew about input and I tried it but I thought it belonged in my parent component!

Comment: If this solvers your problem, can you please accept the answer (white check mark below the up/down-vote buttons) to indicate this question is answered. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `[data]="test"` as follows:

```
<div class='mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet' *ngFor="let test of testData">
        <app-multi-card [data]="testData"></app-multi-card>
      </div>
```

Also, in `app-multi-card` component ts file, have you given `@Input()` declaration for `data` property?

```
@Input() data = ''
```

Refer https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1):

Put `test` instead `testData` in the following sentense and Add an `@Input data` decorator in `app-multi-card` component

```
<app-multi-card [data]="test"></app-multi-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default all the properties of the component are accessible within the component, to expose the property in a parent component to child component you need to explicitly mention by adding a decorator @Input() infront of the property.
In your child-component.ts

```
import Input frm @angular/core.
@Input() data;
```

then you can access *test* which you are assigning in the parent-component.

```
<div class='mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet' *ngFor="let test of testData">
    <app-multi-card [data]="test"></app-multi-card>
</div>
```